# How to get the Update version number of app from playstore?-IONIC

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to show a message to update the app if any updated version is in the playstore.. How to get the code to Know that the app is updated or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Cordova Device Plugin

> Using *CordovaAppVersion* Function and *IonicPopUp*
>
> > Firebase as the database where a **status flag** and **version value** has been set which can be moderated by the admin according to whatsoever newest version of the app is there on playstore.

[image: a busy cat]

```
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

    $cordovaAppVersion.getVersionNumber()
        .then(function (version) {
            var appVersion = version;
            var starCount = firebase.database().ref("version");

            starCount.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.val().ver!=appVersion&&snapshot.val().status===1)
                {
                    versionerr(snapshot.val().ver,appVersion);
                    $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function(e) {
                        //This will restrict the user to close the popup by pressing back key
                         e.preventDefault();
                    },401);
                };
            });
        }); 
    }, false);

versionerr = function(newv,oldv){

    var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
        title: "Update Available",
        template: "A newer version("+n`enter code here`ewv+") of this app is available for download. Please update it from PlayStore ! ",
        subTitle: 'current version : '+oldv,
        scope: $scope,
        buttons: [{ 
            text: 'Exit',
            type: 'button-dark',
            onTap: function(e) {     
                ionic.Platform.exitApp();
            }
        }, {
            text: '<b>Update</b>',
            type: 'button-positive',
            onTap: function(e) {

            $window.open("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ionicframework.hostelcordova596017", '_system');
                ionic.Platform.exitApp();
            }  
        }]
    });
}
```

Comment: Screenshot of the above code -  [Ionic Popup Screenshot](http://www.creatifpixel.com/hostings/Screenshot_20170226-235705.png)